# Finding an item with JQuery whose index matches a count variable

Tags: jquery, image, indexing, each, scroller

I have an image scroller set up, and I keep a count of the current item through a variable called current_item. Now, I want to display the alt text of the image in a list of images whose index matches the item_count.

Here's the JQuery

```
var scroll_text = $('#ax_campaign_content li').index(current_item).children('img').attr('alt');
$('#ax_campaign_scroller h4').text(scroll_text);
```

And this is the basic html structure:

```
<div id="ax_campaign_content">
    <ul>
    <li><img alt="Image 1"></li>
    <li><img alt="Image 2"></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="ax_campaign_scroller">
    <h4>Image Text Goes Here</h4>
</div>
```

This is what I'm trying to do but it's not working. Anybody see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I didn't have any luck with the eq method below. But on second thought - why would I have to even loop through all the items? Couldn't I just use the revised code above - and somehow select the alt text of an item with the index in the list that matches the current_item value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will iterate the `li` elements and then iterate the images inside of that `li`, which will always be just one image. So what you're doing will never get anything related to the `current_item` variable.

Instead you might want to try passing `current_item` to [`.eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to first get the `li` element with that index, and then get the image `alt` attribute:

```
var scroll_text = $("#ax_campaign_content li")
    .eq(current_item)
    .find("img").attr("alt");

$("#ax_campaign_scroller h4")
    .text(scroll_text);
```

Or you can do it with a one-liner (added new-lines and tabs for readability) and select the image in the same selector  without using `.find`:

```
$("#ax_campaign_scroller h4").text(
    $("#ax_campaign_content li:eq("+current_item+") img")
        .attr("alt")
);
```

Comment: Doesn't $(this) only have one child? Due to the each()-function eq() will never find more than one item...

Comment: @Maximilian Ehlers, that's right! I'll update the answer accordigly. Thanks :)

Comment: Awesome! This worked great. Thanks for the help everyone. Just a slight correction - should be eq(current_item) not eq(current_index).

Comment: @mheavers, need more coffee. Just realized I used *THREE* different variable names in there. Corrected!

Answer (score 2):

try eq method - http://api.jquery.com/eq/

```
$('#ax_campaign_content li img').eq(current_item).attr('alt');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your each is looping through each li element, so when you look for img within the each function you are looking inside the li:

```
$(this).children("img").index()
```

Will always return zero, since you only have 1 img inside each li.

Jquery .each already gives you the index, so you can just test that against your current_item like so:

```
$('#ax_campaign_content li').each(function(index) {
        if (index == current_item){
        scroll_text = $(this).children('img').attr('alt');
        $('#ax_campaign_scroller h4').text(scroll_text);
    }
});
```

Responding to the updated comment:
You can always go for the one-liner!

```
$('#ax_campaign_scroller h4').text(
    $('#ax_campaign_content li').eq(current_item).children('img').attr('alt')
);
```

Comment: Yeah you're right on the one-liner. I did do it like that to begin with, but thought this would be easier to understand if you split it up :)